Attaching Ceiling light
My ceiling light has white and black wires. My junction box however doesn’t have a black wire. It has white, blue, green, red, yellow. From what i understand white to white. But black from my light goes to which wire in my junction box. Help will be appreciated. Please. Edit - I live in Toronto ONtario canada. I am not replacing but installing a new light there was no old ceiling light.

wire color code varies from country to country, so where are you

i live in toronto ontario canada

How was the old light wired?  Was there an old light?   Are you replacing it?    Some details for context would be helpful as well as a pic of the wiring in the box and information as to if there is a switch and how that is wired.  Otherwise there is no way to help you.

Electricity doesn't care what color of wire it moves in. The colors are just for human use in differentiating the purpose of wires. In this case your colors are ambiguous, unless these mean something in Canadian electrical code. You need to do some testing to determine which wires are hot/live, neutral, and ground; edit this information into your Question. A photo of your junction box might help get a good answer too.

You would need a multimeter to find the hot wires. Your junction box is ready for light and fan speed control. If you do not use fan, you can ignore 3 wires,
